# Using a button to change NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have searched fairly extensively for this with no luck, I'm pretty sure it trivial.

Essentially, a crystal ball-type app. I have:

```
self.predictionArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"Example 1",    
                        @"example 10000", nil];
```

And a "magic8" button, which when I tap, chooses:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
NSUInteger index = arc4random_uniform(self.predictionArray.count);
self.predictionLabel.text = [self.predictionArray objectAtIndex:index];}
```

This all works perfectly, and there's plenty of stuff on the web about it.

**What I want to do:**

Have 3 of these arrays, and 3 buttons. The button simply selects the corresponding NSArray, then press the "magic8" button.

Seems like it should be fairly simple, I understand what is happening in my current code but I can't for the life of me figure out how to go about it. I'm inexperienced for sure.

Many thanks to anyone who can offer any advice. I really don't want to waste anyone's time, I've had no luck searching and I thought maybe it would take someone knowledgeable ~1min to explain how to go about it.

Comment: I'd suggest you spend a little time learning the basics of programming (with a real book or maybe a classroom course) before trying to write apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to do the 3 button thing:

```
- (IBAction) buttonAction:(UIButton *) b
{
switch(b.tag)
{
case 1:
{
self.predictionArray = nil;
self.predictionArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                    @"Example 1",    
                    @"example 10000", nil];
}
break;

 case 2:
{
self.predictionArray = nil;
self.predictionArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                    @"Example 2",    
                    @"example 20000", nil];
 }

break;
case 3:
{
self.predictionArray = nil;
self.predictionArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                    @"Example 3",    
                    @"example 30000", nil];
 }

break; 
default:
break;
 }

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
NSUInteger index = arc4random_uniform(self.predictionArray.count);
self.predictionLabel.text = [self.predictionArray objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Comment: Ahh, and then when I click say, button2 - it will load its version of the "predictionArray"?

Comment: Yes, that's it , you just switch the content. You can also use 1 method and all 3 buttons can call it, and you set the tags of the buttons 1,2,3 and you just switch the tags and change the content of the array in the method.

Comment: Thanks - this worked perfectly.


I assume it's not a very clean/good way of doing it, but it's worked great for me.

Comment: I think my answer is simpler and cleaner. You don't have to recreate the array over and over.

Comment: Good for you, maybe he doesn't want to create an array of arrays, even if that is indeed much easier.

Answer (score 1):

A simple (but not the best) solution would be to give your 3 buttons in interface builder the tags 0, 1, 2. Then set your `predictionArray` to:

```
@[   @[ @"button 0 123", @"button 0 456" ],
     @[ @"button 1 123", @"button 1 456" ],
     @[ @"button 2 123", @"button 2 456" ]]
```

Then in your `buttonPressed` method you would select the subarray based on your buttons tag:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (sender.tag >= 0 && sender.tag < self.predictionArray.count) {
        NSArray *predictionArray = self.predictionArray[sender.tag];
        NSUInteger index = arc4random_uniform(predictionArray.count);
        self.predictionLabel.text = [predictionArray objectAtIndex:index];
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple but adequate. To clarify for Willl: All three buttons' actions would be connected to this single `buttonPressed:` handler.